# Default constructor curiosity

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, most-vexing-parse

While

```
MyClass m();
```

is a classic gotcha, as it does not declare a variable m, but a function taking zero arguments and returning MyClass. However, I found that in Visual Studio the following statement produces the same problem (it seems it somehow colapses to the above statement):

```
MyClass m( MyClass() );
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Note: A more "explicit" version of what is expected does the right thing (i.e. calls the default, then the move constructor).

```
MyClass m( std::move( MyClass() ) );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the *Most Vexing Parse* problem.

```
MyClass m( MyClass() );
```

This line is parsed like a function named *m* returning object of type *MyClass* and accepting a single argument which is a pointer to a function with no arguments and return value of type *MyClass*.

Here:

```
MyClass m( std::move( MyClass() ) );
```

*std::move* helps compiler to parse the line as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a classical Most Vexing Parse. Everything which looks like a function is a function, even if it could be something else.

There are several legacy methods to translate this into a proper variable definition, but the best one is to use uniform initialization:

```
MyClass m{MyClass()};
```

(Notwithstanding the fact that above example is redundant, and a better example would be when types are different, like `A m{B()};`)